# I want to pass filename and filename2 from the functions sim_file() and meter_file into the function genrate()

Tags: python, function

I want to send the parameters filename and filename2 from the functions sim_file() and meter_file() respectively to the function generate().

```
def sim_file():
        Tk().withdraw()
        filename = askopenfilename()
        return[filename]

def meter_file():
        Tk().withdraw()
        filename2 = askopenfilename()
        return[filename2]

def generate(filename,filename2):
```

The code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the parameters from function by calling them and then call the generate function and pass those parameters to it.

Or you can use them as default parameter as shown below:

```
def sim_file():
        Tk().withdraw()
        filename = askopenfilename()
        return filename

def meter_file():
        Tk().withdraw()
        filename2 = askopenfilename()
        return filename2

#first get parameters by calling function
filename = sim_file()
filename2 = meter_file()
#you can call your function 
generate(filename, filename2)

def generate(filename = filename,filename2 = filename2): # or you can use default value
```